# How to jump multiple lines in emacs?

Tags: help, motion

Suppose I want to jump x amount of lines up or down. Is there a convenient command for it?

Comment: Say you want to jump 5 lines: `c-u 5` and then `c-p`, `c-n` or arrows. A shortcut would be `M-5` and then navigation keys.

Comment: Suppose I want to create my own keybinding to jumping 10 lines. How would I do that?

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: @PrikshetSharma, you can do something like `(global-set-key (kbd "C-p") (lambda () (interactive) (previous-line 5)))`. But I would absolutely not recommend it. You should get used to `c-u number` shortcuts which you can use in other places.

Comment: What @Dan said. This question is about how to find an existing command that does what you want. A different question is how to bind a command to a key. And please use Search here, to see if your question has already been posted (avoid duplicates). With Search you can enter a tag name, in brackets. e.g. `[help]`. Tag `[help]` is about Emacs commands that provide help such as what you're looking for, of which `apropos-command` is one.

Comment: I think I've never had the need to jump eg. exactly ten lines, so just in case if you want to move to a specific place, counting lines and jumping might not be the only or the best approach. Maybe take a look at [movement over expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html).

Answer (score 2):

To discover an existing command that moves up or down lines, use command `apropos-command`, bound to `C-h a` by default.

Commands involving lines often have `line` in their name. So try that: `C-h a line RET`. Among the displayed command names and their descriptions, you'll find `next-line` and `previous-line`.